# Method not found: 'Void Glass.Mapper.Config.set_EnableLazyLoadingForCachableModels(Boolean)'

Tags: glass-mapper

We are upgrading GlassMapper to V5 and installed Glass.Mapper.Sc.90. I have done all the changes and mentioned in http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/documentation/Upgrade-ToV5.html link. After the changes, the solution build successfully.

But at runtime i am getting

> Method not found: 'Void
> Glass.Mapper.Config.set_EnableLazyLoadingForCachableModels(Boolean)'.

Searched many blogs but nothing lead me to the fix. Has anyone got this error? How should i resolve this?

Thanks in Advance,
Yeshwanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the lazy loading has been completely reworked on v5, and this setting is not there anymore. Check your `GlassMapperScCustom.cs` file and see if you have it there, then remove it.

On v5 lazy is enabled by default and you can disable it by passing the param `model.LazyDisabled()` when retrieving your model.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Neither config nor the **GlassMapperScCustom.cs** has that setting. I am sure that I am implementing **model.LazyDisabled()** as mentioned in the Upgrade documentation. But still the above error persists. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I learnt that there is problem with my publish and resolved them. The issue is fixed. Thanks @Miguel Minoldo